# How to implement a form field in SQLAlchemy where multiple choices are possible

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a form (see screenshot) where a user can select multiple options at once.  How would I take these inputs and put them into a single column in a table (perhaps comma separated?) with SQLAlchemy?  Or if there's a better way to do this given that the user can select nearly unlimited options (and I'd like not to have 100 genre fields waiting for inputs in the database), I'm all ears on other ways to implement this.

[image: form with multiple selections possible at a time]

For reference, here's the code I have for the rest of the table:
class Venue(db.Model):
**tablename** = 'Venue'

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String)
city = db.Column(db.String(120))
state = db.Column(db.String(120))
address = db.Column(db.String(120))
phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
genres = #TODO (multiple selections possible from the form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sqlalchemy array types here:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sql-standard-and-multiple-vendor-types

e.g. of usage:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from sqlalchemy.types import ARRAY

genres = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(db.String(255))), default=[])
```